# Create a coordinate node at each point of a path

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, coordinates

How can I create a `TikZ`/`pgf`-style that will put a coordinate, which should be named automatically, at each point of a path?

So the following code

```
\draw[put coordinates](0,0)--(3,2)--(4,7)--(-2,1);
```

Should be essentially the same as:

```
\draw(0,0)--(3,2)--(4,7)--(-2,1);
\coordinate(mypathcoordinate1) at (0,0);
\coordinate(mypathcoordinate2) at (3,2);
\coordinate(mypathcoordinate3) at (4,7);
\coordinate(mypathcoordinate4) at (-2,1);
```

Comment: Should this work for arbitrary paths (with curves and such), and do the paths have to remain closed?

Comment: Generally, the paths should be arbitrary. The coordinates should only lie at the explicitly given points, regardless of the way they are connected (line,move,curve,to,…). Acutely, I only work with -- or to and the paths are closed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a `show path construction` decoration that you apply using a `postaction` to place the `coordinate`s. That way, the underlying path is not changed at all.

Here's a style `put coordinates` that takes an optional argument to name the coordinates (default is `coordinate`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\newcounter{coordinateindex}


\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    put coordinates/.style={
        initialize counter/.code={
            \setcounter{coordinateindex}{0}
        },
        initialize counter,
        decoration={
            show path construction,
            moveto code={
                \stepcounter{coordinateindex}
                \coordinate (#1\thecoordinateindex) at (\tikzinputsegmentfirst);
            },
            lineto code={
                \stepcounter{coordinateindex}
                \coordinate (#1\thecoordinateindex) at (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
            },
            curveto code={
                \stepcounter{coordinateindex}
                \coordinate (#1\thecoordinateindex) at (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
            },
            closepath code={
                \stepcounter{coordinateindex}
                \coordinate (#1\thecoordinateindex) at (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
            },
        },
        postaction={decorate}
    },
    put coordinates/.default=coordinate
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [put coordinates] (0,0) -- (3,2) to [out=90, in=0] (4,7)-- (-2,1);

\foreach \i in {1,...,\thecoordinateindex}{
    \fill (coordinate\i) circle [radius=2pt] node [above left] {\i};
}

\draw [red, put coordinates=secondpath] (0,1) -- (5,4) -- (4,1);
\foreach \i in {1,...,\thecoordinateindex}{
    \fill (secondpath\i) circle [radius=2pt] node [above left] {\i};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```