# TikZ call a macro between subsequent points in a list

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

In TikZ, I would like to build a macro `\drawEdges` which for a given list of points produces code that runs through all pairs of two subsequent points, and runs the `\drawEdge` macro for them. For example,

```
\drawEdges{(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)}
```

should expand to

```
\drawEdge{(0, 0)}{(1, 0)}
\drawEdge{(1, 0)}{(1, 1)}
\drawEdge{(1, 1)}{(0, 1)}
```

The purpose is to cut down on the verbosity of repeating the `\drawEdge` macro on every pair. How can this be done?

Bonus points if you can also provide a cyclic variant where the expansion includes the pair involving the last and the first point:

```
\drawEdge{(0, 1)}{(0, 0)}
```

#### Edit

In my specific case, the `\drawEdge` macro looks something like this:

```
\newcommand{\drawEdge}[2]{
    \draw[edgeStyle, line width = 1pt] #1 -- #2;
    \draw[line width = 0.33pt, draw=white] #1 -- #2;
}
```

Here `edgeStyle` includes a decorator to add a custom-styled arrow tip on a position other than the end, and the latter line hollows out the edge. I would also accept a solution which refactors the process into two separate passes

```
\newcommand{\drawEdgeFirst}[2]{
    \draw[edgeStyle, line width = 1pt] #1 -- #2;
}

\newcommand{\drawEdgeSecond}[2]{
    \draw[line width = 0.33pt, draw=white] #1 -- #2;
}
```

with corresponding `\drawEdgesFirst` and `\drawEdgesSecond`. Then we could do

```
\newcommand{\drawEdges}[1]{
    \drawEdgesFirst{#1}
    \drawEdgesSecond{#1}
}
```

#### Edit 2

Here's an example of the things I'm drawing. Note that I need exact control of how the hollowing of the edge is done (i.e. its width), so that it connects properly with the arrow tips.

[image]

#### Edit 3

Just realized the hollow edges can be drawn using

```
\newcommand{\drawEdge}[2] {
    \draw[edgeStyle, line width = 0.335pt, double distance = 0.33pt] #1 -- #2;
}
```

where the hollowing distance can be controlled precisely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here come the requested macros. I added one possible definition for `\drawEdge`, which you can change. **EDIT**: I corrected the orientation of the last segment. And, more importantly, I also added a way to achieve this with a simple tikz style `separate arrows`. The basic trick is to use the `show path` decoration to draw the segments in the way you suggest. You only have to insert you `\drawEdge` macro into the `lineto code` (and `closepath code`, and you are done. Then a simple

```
\draw[separate arrows] plot coordinates {(0, 0) (1, 0) (1, 1) (0, 1)} -- cycle;
```

does the trick.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings}
\tikzset{separate arrows/.style={%
    decoration={show path construction,
        lineto code={%
            \draw [edgeStyle, line width = 0.2] 
            (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
            \draw[line width = 0.1, draw=white] 
            (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
        },
        closepath code={%
            \draw [edgeStyle, line width = 0.2] 
            (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
            \draw[line width = 0.1, draw=white] 
            (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
        },
     },
    postaction=decorate
}}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\drawEdge}[2]{\draw[edgeStyle, line width = 0.2] #1 -- #2;
    \draw[line width = 0.1, draw=white] #1 -- #2;}
\newcommand{\drawEdges}[1]{%
\foreach [count=\Y] \X in {#1}
{\xdef\tmpLen{\Y}
\ifnum\Y=1
\xdef\myLst{"\X"}
\else
\xdef\myLst{\myLst,"\X"}
\fi}
\xdef\myLst{{\myLst}}
\foreach \X [remember=\X as \Y (initially 1)] in {2,...,\tmpLen}
{\pgfmathsetmacro{\myfrom}{\myLst[\Y-1]}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myto}{\myLst[\X-1]}
\drawEdge{\myfrom}{\myto}
}}
\newcommand{\drawEdgesCyclic}[1]{%
\foreach [count=\Y] \X in {#1}
{\xdef\tmpLen{\Y}
\ifnum\Y=1
\xdef\myLst{"\X"}
\else
\xdef\myLst{\myLst,"\X"}
\fi}
\xdef\myLst{{\myLst}}
\foreach \X [remember=\X as \Y (initially 1)] in {2,...,\tmpLen}
{\pgfmathsetmacro{\myfrom}{\myLst[\Y-1]}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myto}{\myLst[\X-1]}
\drawEdge{\myfrom}{\myto}
}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myfrom}{\myLst[\tmpLen-1]}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myto}{\myLst[0]}
\drawEdge{\myfrom}{\myto}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[edgeStyle/.style={latex-stealth}]
\drawEdges{(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)}
\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm,blue]
\drawEdgesCyclic{(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[yshift=-2cm]
\draw[separate arrows] plot coordinates {(0, 0) (1, 0) (1, 1) (0, 1)};
\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm,blue]
\draw[separate arrows] plot coordinates {(0, 0) (1, 0) (1, 1) (0, 1)}
-- cycle;
\end{scope}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Just for fun: something that approaches your screen shot.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings,calc}
\newcommand{\drawEdge}[2]{
            \draw let \p1=($(#1)-(#2)$),
            \n1={veclen(\x1,\y1} in \ifdim\n1>60pt [edgeStyle={0.3}{-1}, line width = 0.2] 
            (#1) -- (#2)\fi;
            \draw [edgeStyle={0.7}{1}, line width =2pt] 
            (#1) -- (#2);
            \draw[line width = 1, draw=white] 
            (#1) -- (#2);
            \draw[fill=white] (#1) circle (1mm);
            \draw[fill=white] (#2) circle (1mm);
}
\tikzset{separate arrows/.style={%
    decoration={show path construction,
        lineto code={%
            \drawEdge{\tikzinputsegmentfirst}{\tikzinputsegmentlast}
        },
        closepath code={%
            \drawEdge{\tikzinputsegmentfirst}{\tikzinputsegmentlast}
        },
     },
    postaction=decorate
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[edgeStyle/.style n args={2}{-,postaction={decorate,
decoration={markings,mark=at position #1 with {%
\fill[black] (#2*0.25,#2*1pt) -- ({#2*(-0.25)},#2*0.15)
--({#2*(-0.25)},#2*1pt);}}}}]
\draw[separate arrows,fill=gray!30] plot coordinates {(0, 0) (3, 0) (3, 2) (0, 2)}
-- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems like a general solution to the problem! A nitpick: the last edge in the cyclic case is drawn in the wrong direction. Want to elaborate on the plot coordinates? Perhaps that could be used to neatly solve the refactored approach I mention in my edit.

Comment: @kaba Good catch, will update. What you are doing in your edit is done by `\draw[doubble,...]`. Alternatively, you can use `postaction` for that. Do you have an application where one really needs to draw the stuff in this way?

Comment: @kaba I made an update that draws your stuff with a simple Ti*k*Z style.

Comment: I added another edit which demonstrates the kind of things I'm drawing. I think the simple TikZ style here cannot apply a style to each edge separately. I think the show path construction decorator you mentioned in another comment could do the trick.

Comment: @kaba `show path construction` is already part of my updated answer.

Comment: Indeed, I don't know how I missed that. This seems really good.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another proposal that uses a `foreach` loop on all points. Not knowing what your macro is doing, I commented on his call.

#### Update 4 Cyclic at the request of the OP

[image: cyclic]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\newcommand{\drawEdge}[2]{
    \draw[edgeStyle] #1 -- #2;
    \draw[line width = 0.1, draw=white] #1 -- #2;
}

\newcommand{\drawEdges}[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{edgeStyle/.style={blue!75!black,thick,->,>={Straight Barb[angle=50:2pt 3]}}}
\foreach \point [count=\n,remember=\point as \p (initially \point)] in
{(0,0),(1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)}
{   \node (point\n) at \point {};

}
\foreach \i [remember= \i as \lasti (initially \n)]in {1,...,\n}{
\drawEdge{(point\lasti.center)}{(point\i.center)}

}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\drawEdges{(0,0),(1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)}
\end{document}
```

#### Update 3

Another possibility with the `ifthen else` test:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\drawEdge}[2]{
    \draw[edgeStyle] #1 -- #2;
    \draw[line width = 0.1, draw=white] #1 -- #2;
}

\newcommand{\drawEdges}[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{edgeStyle/.style={blue,line width = 0.2}}
\foreach \point [remember=\point as \p (initially \point)] in
{#1}
{ ifthen {\p=\point} {}
    {\drawEdge{\p}{\point}}
}

\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\drawEdges{(0,0),(1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### Second update (to answer OP's comment)

[image: DrawEdges]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\drawEdge}[2]{
    \draw[edgeStyle] #1 -- #2;
    \draw[line width = 0.1, draw=white] #1 -- #2;
}

\newcommand{\drawEdges}[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{edgeStyle/.style={blue,line width = 0.2}}
\foreach \point [remember=\point as \p (initially \point)] in
{#1}
{
    \drawEdge{\p}{\point}
}

\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\drawEdges{(0,0),(1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### Update

I have removed the parentheses around the parameters of your macro `\DrawEdge` since the `foreach` loop performs an iteration on point coordinates including parentheses.

[image: edges]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\drawEdge}[2]{
    \draw[edgeStyle] #1 -- #2;
    \draw[line width = 0.1, draw=white] #1 -- #2;
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{edgeStyle/.style={blue,line width = 0.2}}
\foreach \point [remember=\point as \p (initially {(0,0)})] in
{(1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)}
{
    \drawEdge{\p}{\point}
%    \draw[red] \p -- \point circle(1mm);
}

\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm]
\foreach \point [remember=\point as \p (initially {(0,1)})] in
{(0,0),(1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)}
{
    \drawEdge{\p}{\point}
%    \draw[blue] \p -- \point circle(1mm);
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### Old answer

[image: draw-edge]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \point [remember=\point as \p (initially {(0,0)})] in
{(1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)}
{
    %\\drawEdge{\p}{\point}
    \draw[red] \p -- \point circle(1mm);
}

\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm]
\foreach \point [remember=\point as \p (initially {(0,1)})] in
{(0,0),(1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)}
{
    %\\drawEdge{\p}{\point}
    \draw[blue] \p -- \point circle(1mm);
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How would you define the macro `\drawEdges`? The difficulty seems to be in extracting the first or last point in the list, which is done manually here.

Comment: I just updated my answer

Comment: I think the new solution draws a line from the first point to itself, which is sometimes visible when the end-points are drawn differently.

Comment: Yes, it all depends on the options of your macro. Most of the time, it doesn't trace anything at all.

Comment: With an `ifthen else` test, it does not trace anything at the first iteration.

Comment: That is a nice simple idea! The problem is the test against a coordinate, since there can be multiple equal coordinates. However, you could instead use `count` to test for the first iteration instead of the coordinate.

Comment: I wonder if you could solve the cyclic version similarly by storing the first point in the first iteration, and then do a final `\drawEdge` at the end?

Comment: I just updated my answer

Comment: The latest two solve both problems in a simple way! The answer could do with some cleaning: the first attempts need not be shown, using count for non-cyclic version, and using scope instead of tikzpicture to create a scope :)

Comment: The first versions allow everyone, especially beginners, to understand the latest versions. Updates show the progress and allow to understand how the different problems have been solved. In my opinion, this progressiveness should never be removed from the presentation.

Answer (score 2):

If `\drawEdge` draws lines, then one can use `plot coordinates{<coordinates>}` to achieve this.

A MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[smooth cycle,tension=0] plot coordinates{(0,0) (0,1) (1,1) (1,0)};
\draw[red] plot coordinates{(0,2) (0,3) (1,3) (1,2)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a difference between plot coordinates and drawing a path? Each edge should be drawn separately, so for example if the edge's style contains a decorator, then that decorator should be applied to each edge.

Comment: Your answer reminded me of the correct syntax: `plot coordinates`, not just `coordinates`, +1 for that. ;-) @kaba As I mentioned in my answer at the very end, you can do all the decorations and so on, see e.g. [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/463951/121799), where there is a marking decoration on each connection between two points.